# Calling external py modules from jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a project structure like this

[image]

I have some functions in `utils.py` which I want to use in `aNotebook`, so ran the `pip install --editable` command on my project and put the following in the first cell of the notebook

```
    %load_ext autoreload
    %autoreload 2
```

This I believe should allow me to do

```
    import src.constants
    from src.utils import write_data

    write_data(....)
```

But I'm having an issue where the *constants* defined in `constants.py` don't seem to stick.  In other words, the functions in `utils.py` that are depending on the *constants* are not being defined at runtime.

What's more, in order to ensure that the *constants* are available to the function in `utils.py` without requiring the user to know they are required, `utils.py` imports the `constants.py`

**My question**, is there a primer on how to use Jupyter notebooks with plain old python modules such that both can reside in the same project?  This seems like a lot of work for something that should be easy.

EDIT: Adding MVC and error

[image]

[image]

*** contents of src\utils.py

```
def test1():
    return 'got to the test program'
```

Comment: Just so I understand correctly, in your utils.py you run `from constants import *` and when you import from utils.py these constants are undefined?

Comment: Yes, they are undefined in the Jupyter notebook and they don't seem to stick in the code

Comment: can you run an example and add a traceback error in your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
import os
import sys
# This adds the project root to the searchpath
sys.path.append(os.path.pardir)

# Then I can use 
from src.utils import test1
```